# Near: AssemblyScript NEP141 is not showed in wallet

Tags: nearprotocol, assemblyscript

I was trying to build a NEP141 token with assemblyscript and to deploy it on the Near Network, but, after the deployment, I'm not able to see it on the wallet.
I checked my work with the one in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTQeumO2oOY&t=9s) from the Near YouTube channel and our projects looks similar.

After looking how NEP141 are made with Rust I have 3 questions:

1. In the Rust SDK, we have a module to define some contract standards ([link to near-sdk-rs standars](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/near-contract-standards/src/fungible_token)). Do we have something like that for the as-sdk?
2. In the NEP141 documentation, the types of the variables returned by some methods are not aligned with the types returned in the near-sdk-rs standard. For example, the method ft_balance_of in the Near documentation should return a string variable ([documentation link](https://nomicon.io/Standards/FungibleToken/Core)), but in the Rust SDK it returns a U128 ([near-rs-sdk link to standards](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/9d99077c6acfde68c06845f2a1eb2b5ed7983401/near-contract-standards/src/fungible_token/core.rs)).
   Which one is the right one? (I guess is the rust one)
3. Is the near-sdk-as still supported? There are some pull requests open from 2020 and they are still not merged.
   In particular, I had a problem trying to compile the source code in the Near Youtube Video. The problem would be fixed if this [pull request](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-as/pull/697) would be merged.

thanks!

Comment: AssemblyScript doesn't have U128, so I believe `string` is used to be able to use large "numbers".

Comment: I'm not sure about your answer because we don't have U128 in assemblyscript, but we do have u128 in near-sdk-as, so I think it would be better to use that type to be aligned with rs.

Comment: I can confirm.
If you try to implement the NEP141 methods as strings, the near wallet will give you the error: "Error: [big.js] Invalid number".

You have to implement those methods as u128/U128.